# Can't install Boot Camp ("no bootable device" error)

Tags: mac, partitioning

I just bought a MacBook Pro and I am trying to install Boot Camp software so that I can install and use Microsoft Publisher (it didn't come with the Windows for Mac software I purchased).

I have already installed the Windows software and I am trying to create the partition in the hard drive.

I inserted the CD with the OS X for Windows software and followed the instructions.  The screen went black and the message on the screen says

> `No bootable device-- insert boot disk and press any key`

The cursor is blinking and the machine is not responding to any commands.

Comment: Are you sure you told it to boot to the CD?

Answer (score 1):

You run bootcamp from the Mac OS, you don't need to boot up from a Windows disk.
Follow the prompts on starting up Bootcamp and you should be OK.
You'll need a Windows XP SP2 or later disk and the install disks that came with the Mac.